# Chinese Galaxy note has no google account

Tags: sync, google-account

I am using a Galaxy note [GT i9220], it has samsung account for cloud synchronization but no google account.

I9220ZCLSF

It supports Chinese / Korean / English language only.
using Android 4.1.2

It seems I could set up gmail through exchange synchronization which is not so efficient.

1. Is there a way to enable google account ?
2. Once solved, can I sync contact both to Samsung and Gooogle cloud ?

UPDATE: I just want a google account for email, addressbook and calendar sync. Do I necessarily need to flash cyanogen mod to enable google account ?